# How to pass variable from python3 to javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, arguments

I make a connection with DB and select some information with a query in a python file. All information is stored in a variable. Then I start a js, but I want to send this information from python to the js file to use it there. Should I start the script like with some argument and how should I get it in the js file?

Comment: you might want to read about web frameworks like flask.

Comment: What exactly does that mean, "start a js"…?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an `json` file that contain all your data ? Run your python script then update this json and finally call your js file that import this json

With es6 its easy to import a json in a js file :

```
import * as data from './example.json';
```

Comment: Sounds a bit messy for this, ie. reading from/writing to the filesystem.

Comment: In keeping with UNIX traditions, the data should (optionally) simply be written to stdout and could be piped into the other program from there.